# Creating admin Menu

Tags: magento2

Hi am new to magento am trying to learn creating admin menu in magento 2 
[image]

when i clcik on customercustomattribute it directly goes to admin grid but i want to add another field manage attributes and on the click of manage attribute it should go to admin grid. 
here is my 
**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Eecom. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom_index" title="Customer Custom Attribute" module="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute"  sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute" action="customcustomerattribute/custom/index" resource="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom_index"/>
<!--AddMenu-->
    </menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom_index" title="Customer Custom Attribute" module="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute"  sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute"  resource="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom_index"/>
        <add id="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom_manage" title="Manage attributes" module="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute"  sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute" action="customcustomerattribute/custom/index" resource="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom_index" parent="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom_index"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: yeah it works thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom" title="Customer" module="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute" sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute" resource="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom" />

        <add id="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom" module="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute" sortOrder="10" parent="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::trademe" title="Customer Attribute" resource="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom" />
        <add id="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom_index" title="Customer Custom Attribute" module="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute" sortOrder="20" parent="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom_index" action="customcustomerattribute/custom/index" resource="Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::eecom_custom_index" />
    </menu>
</config>
```